# Grails app not started using searchable

Tags: grails, lucene, searchable, grails-searchable, searchable-plugin

I am having some problems trying to start up in production a grails app that is using searchable and the only log that I have is

```
2014-01-21 20:45:16,622 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO  analyzer.LuceneAnalyzerManager  - Building analyzer [searchableplugin_simple]
2014-01-21 20:45:16,627 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO  analyzer.LuceneAnalyzerManager  - Building analyzer [searchableplugin_whitespace]
```

Does anybody know why I am having this problem and how can I get more information about the problem?

UPDATE: Well, it was basically a problem with permissions in tomcat. No less no more. It was trying to write the index in a non-allowed folder.

Comment: What is your logging level set to in Production, Fran? I'd try to turn up verbosity to get more information. Including Grails version, Searchable version and if everything is ok in pre-production environments could be relevant also.

Comment: Also check the the version of Java being used in prod... I've run into a similar issue where the prod server was using a non-Oracle version.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I will do it tonight to find more. I think I am using open-jdk but I am not 100% sure.